# Unable to modify server by programming since SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a c# program which connects to a server SQL to create a data base.

everything was working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 but with Microsoft SQL Server 2014 i am facing some issues.

**My code is :**

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(instanceName));
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

server.Settings.LoginMode = mode;
server.Alter();
```

And the Alter command throw the exception : **"Fail to modify for server"**

I have tried  this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013 but it doesn't work.

**EDIT1:**
Exception (sorry I use french version of Visual) :

**Message :** Échec de Modifier pour Serveur « .\SQLEXPRESS ». 
=> Fail to Modify for Server « .\SQLEXPRESS »

**GetType() :** Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException

**StackTrace :**    à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()

**InnerException** : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: Une exception s'est produite lors de l'exécution d'une instruction ou d'un lot Transact-SQL. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplFinish(StringCollection alterQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplWorker()

à Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()

**Data :** System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

**Source :** Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Comment: please provide total exception'

Comment: I have more information for the exception (EDIT1)

Comment: please update  question with total exception

Comment: wild guess: on the new server the account used for the connection is not granted 'create database' permission.

Comment: I had admin permission and i have the problem.
But I gave permission for NT AUTORITY\System and it look to be working
Why do i have to give permission for SQL SERVER 2014 but not with SQL SERVER 2008 ?